# How i save multiple request.POST.get() in form.save()

Tags: python, django

I wanna get data with `request.POST.get()` and then save in `form.save()`. How I can solve that?

```py
def example(request):
        form = addform()
        if (request.method == 'POST'):
            form = addform(request.POST)
            question = request.POST.get('question')
            answer = request.POST.get('answer')
            explain = request.POST.get('explain')

            if (form.is_valid()):
                form.save() # i wann save all (question + answer + explain) here in form.
                

        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'Example_fragenkatalog.html', context)
```

I hope someone can help me! Thank you!

Comment: pass `form = addform(request.POST, question=question, answer=answer, explain=explain)
` after the `if (form.is_valid())` before `form.save()` to see if that works.

Comment: Is this a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#creating-forms-from-models)?  If so, then calling `form.save()` will do all the work - you need not get the individual values.  If it is **not** a `ModelForm` then it will not have a `save()` method.  In that case, where, what models are you trying to save the information in?